# Two different camel routes using same connection with netty4

Tags: sockets, synchronization, apache-camel, netty

I have two routes using netty4 component that should read and write to same socket connection but for some reason is not working as it should.

The first one

```
from("netty4:tcp://SERVER:PORT?decoder=#packet-decoder&encoder=#packet-encoder&clientMode=true")
.to("seda:inbound")
```

The second:

```
from("seda:dispatch")
.to("netty4:tcp://SERVER:PORT?decoder=#packet-decoder&encoder=#packet-encoder&sync=true&reuseChannel=true")
.process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                          logger.info("Packet received: " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
                    }
                });
```

Please note that the first one (the "from" one) is configured as a client and the second one (the "to" one) is a client in nature.

Even though I'm using the reuseChannel in the second one and the "PacketEncoder" encode method is being called, not exceptions is being thrown, the data is not being sent.

```
public class PacketEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Packet> { 

    public PacketEncoder() { 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet packet, ByteBuf out) throws Exception { 
        out.writeBytes(PacketUtil.convertPacketToBytes(packet, true)); 
    } 

}
```

Finally, in the second route, the processor after the "to" endpoint is never called. The follow is getting stuck somewhere inside the NettyProducer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello @Guilherme Ramos. Have you ever find the solution for this issue. I am solving the same problem right now. Thanks.

Comment: Not really @mr.pohl, I ended not using camel for this implementation unfortunately. Maybe the newer version of camel are able to do it nowadays. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route>
        <description>test</description>
        <from uri="activemq:Test" />
        <to   uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:22822?clientMode=true&amp;sync=true&amp;allowDefaultCodec=false&amp;reuseChannel=true"/>
    </route>
<route>
        <description>Connessione dal ControlCenter alla coda</description>
        <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:22822?clientMode=true&amp;sync=true&amp;decoders=#string-decoder&amp;reuseChannel=true" />
        <to   uri="activemq:Test2"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I use this but dont work everytime a new tcp client are opened

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you shoul add the reuseChannel option also to the first endpoint, the “from”. The channel is saved in the exchange, so the option must be set in the endpoint where the exchange is created.